# Setting virtualenv to use a compiled from source python as bin

Tags: python, virtualenv

I need to force a virtualenv to use a compiled source python on my ci server (long story short: travis ci support python 2.7.3. heroku works with 2.7.6 and we insist on testing in the same environment as production) . But I fail to get virtualenv to run against it.

travis first runs this script:

```
if [ ! -d ./compiled ]; then
    echo "creating compiled folder"
    mkdir compiled
else
    echo "compiled exists"
fi

cd compiled

if [ ! -e Python-2.7.6.tar.xz ]; then
    echo "Downloading python and compiling"
    wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
    tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
    cd Python-2.7.6
    ./configure
    make
    chmod +x ./python

else
    echo "Compiled python exists!"
fi
```

and then:

```
- virtualenv -p ./python ./compiled/python276
- source ./compiled/python276/bin/activate
```

but when then doing `python --version` shows 2.7.3 instead of 2.7.6

Guess I'm missing something, Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the full path(or relative to home) of the compiled python binary?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the virtualenv folder, and open bin/ folder:

```
~/.Virtualenv/my_project/bin
```

Remove 'python' file, and create a symbolic link to the python executable, that you want to use, like:

```
cd ~/.Virtualenv/my_project/bin
mv python python-bkp
ln -s /usr/bin/python .
```